# Python string replacement in a Dockerfile inserts on a new line

Tags: python, string, docker

I'm writing a small Python app that compares the package used in a Dockerfile (Alpine3.15) to the package version on the Alpine packages website (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages). It's just a test project that could possibly automate the updating of this particular package. (I'm aware this doesn't seem like the ideal way though!)

This program scrapes the appropriate site page for the apk version using Beautiful Soup. The program then formats this and leaves only the version of the package, stored in a variable.

The app then compares the apk version scraped from the site to the version in the Dockerfile. If there is a difference then the version in the Dockerfile is replaced with the version scraped from the site.

However, when I replace the old Dockerfile apk version with the current scraped version it inserts it onto a new line, rather than replacing it on the line it was on.

Any help for how to replace the apk version on the same line would be appreciated:

```
#Code for replacing the old cert with the new

def cert_updater(cert_apk):
    df_cert = cert_apk
    df_cert = cert_formatter(df_cert)                #Strips away everything but the apk version
    current_cert = certificate_version(parsed_page)  #Scrapes the site for current apk version and formats it so only the version is returned

    with open('./hardened-image/Dockerfile', 'r') as r:
        replacement_cert = r.read().replace(df_cert, current_cert)
    with open('./hardened-image/Dockerfile', 'w') as w:
        w.write(replacement_cert)
    
    r.close()
    w.close()
```

But when I run the above, the Dockerfile goes from this:

```
RUN apk add -u \
    ca-certificates=111111 \
    git=3.10
```

to this (I know I'll need to add on a \ too):

```
RUN apk add -u \
    ca-certificates=
20211220    git=3.10
```

So far I've tried other ways of replacing the file string, but that hasn't worked either!

Comment: Does this really have anything to do with Docker? Please extract and provide a [mcve]! BTW, a hint to trigger a thought: Why do you open files with `with`?

Comment: Looks like `current_cert` is prefixed with`\n`. Try `current_cert = certificate_version(parsed_page).strip()` or call `.strip` on the return value inside `certificate_version`.

Comment: This worked for me. Was the indicator of the prefixed \n the 'RUN apk' line?

Issue was fixed by doing:

'''
with open('./hardened-image/Dockerfile', 'r') as r:
        replacement_cert = r.read().replace(df_cert, current_cert + " \  \n")
'''